# Javascript function won't build an SVG on IE11

Tags: javascript, html, svg, internet-explorer-11

I'm creating Google Analytic like graphs using SVGs to plot the data along points.  I've sourced a function that will accept an array of points and build them into a path element which is inserted into an SVG on a HTML page.  This function has been successful across Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Safari, but when it gets to IE11 it doesn't even output the  element.

I believe the compatibility issue lies within the svgPath(); function.  I've read that IE11 doesn't support ES6 javascript, and I'm wondering if someone with a better understanding of IE11 and javascript could help diagnose what's the cause of the issue.

FYI if i copy the path code out of the DOM on a browser where it works and directly place it in the HTML it does work on IE11.  So the issue seems to be entirely on the javascript function and not the SVG not displaying for IE11.

**Javascript:**

```
var points = [
    [5, 10],
    [10, 40],
    [40, 30],
    [60, 5],
    [90, 45],
    [120, 10],
    [150, 45],
    [200, 10]
];

// Render the svg <path> element 
// I:  - points (array): points coordinates
//     - command (function)
//       I:  - point (array) [x,y]: current point coordinates
//           - i (integer): index of 'point' in the array 'a'
//           - a (array): complete array of points coordinates
//       O:  - (string) a svg path command
// O:  - (string): a Svg <path> element
var svgPath = function svgPath(points, command) {
  // build the d attributes by looping over the points
  var d = points.reduce(function (acc, point, i, a) {return i === 0 ? 'M ' +
    point[0] + ',' + point[1] :
    acc + ' ' + command(point, i, a);},
  '');
  return '<path d="' + d + '" fill="none" stroke="grey" />';
};

// Svg path line command
// I:  - point (array) [x, y]: coordinates
// O:  - (string) 'L x,y': svg line command
var lineCommand = function lineCommand(point) {return 'L ' + point[0] + ' ' + point[1];};

var svg = document.querySelector('.svg');
svg.innerHTML = svgPath(points, lineCommand);
```

**HTML:**

```
<svg version="1.1" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    width="1000" 
    height="200" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    viewBox="0 0 200 50" 
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" 
    class="svg">

    </svg>
```

The string the function should be returning, but isn't on IE11:

```
<path d="M 5,10 L 10 40 L 40 30 L 60 5 L 90 45 L 120 10 L 150 45 L 200 10" fill="none" stroke="grey"></path>
```

Screenshot of Graph in Chrome:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj51y.jpg

Screenshot of Graph in IE11:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOgNf.jpg

And finally the source from where I got the javascript function:
https://medium.com/@francoisromain/smooth-a-svg-path-with-cubic-bezier-curves-e37b49d46c74
https://codepen.io/francoisromain/pen/dzoZZj

Comment: innerHTML on IE will not create SVG elements properly, you'd need to use document.createElementNS to create elements individually in the right namespace. I believe innerHTML was fixed in Edge and works all other modern browsers.

Comment: I agree with Robert Longson: use javascript to create the value for the d attribute and then use `pathName.setAttributeNS(null,"d","M 5,10 L 10 40 L 40 30 L 60 5 L 90 45 L 120 10 L 150 45 L 200 10")`

Comment: Thanks for your help guys.  Paul used the technique you mentioned which has got it working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robert said, you can't use `innerHTML` to create SVG elements in IE 11.  You have to create the elements yourself. To create an SVG `<path>` element, you use:

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
```

Then you add the attributes you want using `setAttribute()`.

```js
var points = [
    [5, 10],
    [10, 40],
    [40, 30],
    [60, 5],
    [90, 45],
    [120, 10],
    [150, 45],
    [200, 10]
];

// Render the svg <path> element 
// I:  - points (array): points coordinates
//     - command (function)
//       I:  - point (array) [x,y]: current point coordinates
//           - i (integer): index of 'point' in the array 'a'
//           - a (array): complete array of points coordinates
//       O:  - (string) a svg path command
// O:  - (string): a Svg <path> element
var svgPath = function svgPath(svg, points, command) {
  // build the d attributes by looping over the points
  var d = points.reduce(function (acc, point, i, a) {return i === 0 ? 'M ' +
    point[0] + ',' + point[1] :
    acc + ' ' + command(point, i, a);},
  '');
  var path = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, "path");
  path.setAttribute("d", d);
  path.setAttribute("fill", "none");
  path.setAttribute("stroke", "grey");
  return path;
};

// Svg path line command
// I:  - point (array) [x, y]: coordinates
// O:  - (string) 'L x,y': svg line command
var lineCommand = function lineCommand(point) {return 'L ' + point[0] + ' ' + point[1];};

var svg = document.querySelector('.svg');
svg.appendChild( svgPath(svg, points, lineCommand) );
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    width="1000" 
    height="200" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    viewBox="0 0 200 50" 
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" 
    class="svg">

</svg>
```

Comment: Just tested this and it's worked a charm.  Thanks so much for preparing the correct code! Lifesavers.